# is it possible to use a component/module from angular 15 in angular js currently?

Tags: angular, angularjs, ng-upgrade

I have an angularjs application in the most current version, 1.8. and I want to be able to use angular 15 components in my app using ngupgrade downgradeComponent/downgradeModule function, however all the information I've found is a bit old and it's not clear to me what the specific process is to do it.

What interests me is that my angularjs app is the bootstrap of the application. and that the angular component is the one that is added as a directive.

for example:

```
angular.bootstrap(
  document,
  [angularAppModule],
  { strictDi: true }
);
```

It is only an idea about the approach that I'm searching.